# CentOS rsyslog how to split log files by date?

Tags: linux, centos, logging, centos7, rsyslog

In the `/var/log/ directory`, we can see that the messages logs are split by a date stamp, roughly every week. Logs older than one month are automatically deleted.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls -lh /var/log/
total 12G
-rw-------  1 root   root   1.5G Nov  5 09:56 messages
-rw-------  1 root   root   195K Oct 13 03:10 messages-20191013
-rw-------  1 root   root   1.5G Oct 20 03:43 messages-20191020
-rw-------  1 root   root   4.5G Oct 27 03:29 messages-20191027
-rw-------  1 root   root   4.5G Nov  3 03:06 messages-20191103
```

I created a customized log entry in the `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file, like below:

```
kern.warning         /var/log/iptables/iptables.log
```

The log entry works normally, but the problem is, the log file keeps growing without automatically splitting itself, so the file size grows larger and larger.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls -lh /var/log/iptables/
total 12G
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  18 Oct 14 11:10 ftp
-rw------- 1 root root 12G Nov  5 09:56 iptables.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   6 Oct 14 10:59 mnt
```

I googled very much about how to split rsyslog log file, but find no valuable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files are rotated by [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate). You have files under /etc/logrotate.d/* that dictate how this is handled.